# Let Z=E(X|Y). Show that Var(X) = Var(Z) + E(Var(X|Y)). So that in particular, we have Var(Z) $\le$ Var(X)

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble proving this:

Let Z=E(X|Y). Show that Var(X) = Var(Z) + E(Var(X|Y)). So that in particular, we have Var(Z) $\le$ Var(X)

This is what I have so far:

$Var(Z) = E(Z^2)-(EZ)^2$

$Var(Z) = E((E(X|Y)^2)-[E(E(X|Y))]^2$

$Var(Z) = E((E(X|Y)^2)-(EX)^2$

Then I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Use that $Var(X)  + (EX)^2 = E(X^2)$ (you can verify this using the definition of variance). Combine that with your work on the previous lines to obtain the desired identity.

Comment: So Var(Z)= E((E(X|Y)^2) − [E(X^2) - Var(X)] <=>
      Var(Z)= E((E(X|Y)^2) − E(X^2) + Var(X) <=>
      Var(X)= Var (Z) + E((E(X|Y)^2) − E(X^2)

How do I simply the last part?

Comment: @Domo .. and the last part is $\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)^2) - \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y)) = \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(X\mid Y))$

Comment: @BlueBuck $ Var(Z) = E[E(X|Y)^2] - E[E[X^2|Y)] +Var(X) $
Not sure I am on the right track and what to do after this.