# Var(S) = E(Var(S|T)) + Var(E(S|T))

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $S$ and $T$ be any statistics.   
Given that $\mathsf {Var}(S)$ is finite, prove that
$$\mathsf {Var}(S) = \mathsf {E}(\mathsf {Var}(S\mid T)) + \mathsf {Var}(\mathsf {E}(S\mid T))$$

Any hints?   Suggestions?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706394/let-z-exy-show-that-varx-varz-evarxy-so-that-in-particular-we?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Var(X|Y)=E((X-E(X|Y))^2|Y)=E(X^2|Y)-E(X|Y)^2$, $Var(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ and $E(E(X|Y))=E(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

To begin: use the definition of variance, and the Law of Iterated Expectation.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Var}(S) =&~ \mathsf E(S^2)-\mathsf {E}(S)^2\\ =&~\mathsf E(\mathsf E(S^2\mid T))-\mathsf E(\mathsf E(S\mid T))^2 \\=&~ ... \end{align}$$

To do: the rest.  Can you?